# How to implement smooth scrolling to section on different page when an anchor link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, smooth-scrolling

Since I made some progress, I'm editing this post.
My main menu is horizontally on top of the page, with `position:fixed`. I want to make it so that, when a link gets clicked, the page scrolls down smoothly to the respective target. Because of my sticky header, said target needs to get displayed with an offset from the viewport top.

My HTML/CSS:

```
<style>
#main_menu {
 position: fixed;
}
</style>
<body>

<nav id="main_menu">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="different-page.html#link3">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

main section of index.html:

```
<main>
<h1 id="link1">Heading 1</h1>
<!-- some content -->
<h1 id="link2">Heading 2</h1>
<!-- some content -->
</main>
```

main section of different-page.html:

```
<main>
<!-- some content -->
<!-- some content -->
<!-- some content -->
<!-- some content -->
<h1 id="link3">Heading 3</h1>
<!-- some content -->
</main>
```

EDIT:
I'm now using this for smooth scrolling between sections:

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {

  if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
    var target = $(this.hash);

    target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
    if (target.length) {
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top - 220
      }, 1000);
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

It's working for smooth scrolling between sections on one page. But if I link to a section on a different page, it's not working correctly.
Example:
`<li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>` to `<h1 id="link1">Heading 1</h1>` works. On click, the page scrolls down to heading 1 and heading 1 is then shown 200px below the viewport top and doesn't get covered by my sticky header.
`<li><a href="different-page.html#link3">Link 3</a></li>` links from index.html to section `<h1 id="link3">Heading 3</h1>` on `different-page.html` This also works, except the offset of -200 gets ignored. This means the section top aligns with the viewport top, so it gets covered by the sticky navigation.
I'm guessing that going to a new page somehow messes with my js? I would like it to always mind the offset so that, when I link to a specific section on another page, this section loads 200px away from the viewport top (so below my header, not underneath).
Hope I explained this right.

Answer (score 0):

I change the code Some CSS changes-

```
  <style>
   html {
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
 }
    #main_menu {
    position: fixed;
 }
  </style>
 <body>

   <nav id="main_menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#link1">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link2">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#link3">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

   <main style="overflow-y:scroll;height:58vh">
   <h1 id="link1">Heading 1</h1>
   <!-- some content -->
  <h1 id="link2">Heading 2</h1>
   <!-- some content -->
  <h1 id="link3">Heading 3</h1>
 <!-- some content -->
   </main>
   <script>
 // ???
 </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, though it adds a scrollbar to the `main` section. `I also figured that scroll-behavior: smooth;` doesn't have great cross-browser support. So I'm thinking a js solution would be best. I've looked more into finding one and updated my original post.